# youtube scraper requests & urllib.parse

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

trying to get sub count for each video channel I get but don't know why it's not working

```
class YoutubeSearch:

    def __init__(self, search_terms: str, max_results=None):
        self.search_terms = search_terms
        self.max_results = max_results
        self.videos = self._search()

    def _search(self):
        encoded_search = urllib.parse.quote_plus(self.search_terms)
        BASE_URL = "https://youtube.com"
        url = f"{BASE_URL}/results?search_query={encoded_search}"
        response = requests.get(url).text
        while "ytInitialData" not in response:
            response = requests.get(url).text
        results = self._parse_html(response)
        if self.max_results is not None and len(results) > self.max_results:
            return results[: self.max_results]
        return results

    def _parse_html(self, response):
        results = []
        start = (
            response.index("ytInitialData")
            + len("ytInitialData")
            + 3
        )
        end = response.index("};", start) + 1
        json_str = response[start:end]
        data = json.loads(json_str)

        videos = data["contents"]["twoColumnSearchResultsRenderer"]["primaryContents"][
            "sectionListRenderer"
        ]["contents"][0]["itemSectionRenderer"]["contents"]

        # get subscriberCountText from each video
        for video in videos:
            res = {}
            if "videoRenderer" in video.keys():
                video_data = video.get("videoRenderer", {})
                #res["id"] = video_data.get("videoId", None)
                res["title"] = video_data.get("title", {}).get("runs", [[{}]])[0].get("text", None)
                #res["channel"] = video_data.get("longBylineText", {}).get("runs", [[{}]])[0].get("text", None)
                res["url_suffix"] = video_data.get("navigationEndpoint", {}).get("commandMetadata", {}).get("webCommandMetadata", {}).get("url", None)
                res["subscribers"] = video_data.get("subscriberCountText", {}).get("simpleText", 0)
                results.append(res)


        return results

    def to_json(self, clear_cache=True):
        result = json.dumps({"videos": self.videos})
        if clear_cache:
            self.videos = ""
        return result
```

Everthing works except sub count and I know it's semantic error

in

```
res["subscribers"] = video_data.get("subscriberCountText", {}).get("simpleText", 0)
```

for subscriberCountText i think i should get each channel data i get but how?

Comment: no erros just when print sub: {v['subscribers']} sub count always will be 0

Comment: You should use the Youtube API, not parse the html.

Comment: need something free

Comment: The YouTube API is free as far as I'm aware. The [python-youtube](https://pypi.org/project/python-youtube/) library seems to be a match for what you need.